# validate if user has permission to access the webapp using SAPUI5

Tags: authorization, sapui5

can someone please help me to code the logic for this, especially a logic for return "boolean that user is authorized". And if ever I did some mistakes here feel free to correct me. Thank you

```
validateUserAccess: function () {
        BusyIndicator.show(0);
        var that = this;
        var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
        

        var fnSuccess = function (oData) {
            BusyIndicator.hide();
            //return boolean that user is authorized
            
        };

        var fnError = function (error) {
            BusyIndicator.hide();
            //navigate to error page
            return this.getRoute.navTo("NotAuthorized");
        };

        oModel.read("/EntitySetFromBackend" + user loggedIn EID + "')", {
            success: fnSuccess,
            error: fnError
        });
    },
```

Comment: I would follow a different approach. If a user is not authed they shouldn't even be able to load the metadata. Or if this is in a launchpad, they shouldn't even be able to open the tile. However this is not something you solve with code.

Comment: What do I need to do about this? I really don't have an idea. This app is not in the launchpad, so I thought that there is something I can do to implement authorization in my code. Btw, thanks for answering :)

Comment: Create a role which contains the OData service as an authorization object: https://answers.sap.com/questions/11891194/authorization-for-consuming-odata-service.html